# R package rvest() working, but not giving the result of filling out the HTML form

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm stumped, not sure what I'm doing wrong (using rvest()):

```
url <- "http://library.uaf.edu"    
a_session <- session(url)
a_form <- html_form(a_session)
filled_form <- html_form_set(a_form[[1]],ebscohostsearchtext="SQL")
#
a_returned_info <- html_form_submit(filled_form)
returned_page <- rawToChar(a_returned_info$content)
big_pile_of_html <- read_html(returned_page)
#writeLines(text=returned_page,con=file(FILENAMEHERE))
```

PROBLEM:  When I look at the output from the last line in a browser, I see the original page (obtained by 'url'), and not the page that should be created when the SQL is submitted to the field.  Otherwise, output is reasonable HTML.  Also, the status code for a_returned_info is 200, which should be a success.

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible? What is `url` ?